# Check the file's encoding is Shift-JIS (Encoding.GetEncoding(932)) in C#

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, csvhelper, shift-jis

I have a problem.

When a read csv file with CSVHelper in C#.

I want to get the encoding of the file and check if it is Shift-JIS (Encoding Japan) or not.

I researched a lot but couldn't find the answer.

Any help or ideas?

Thank a lot.

Comment: Try Ude (a [C# port of Mozilla Universal Charset Detector](https://github.com/errepi/ude)).

Comment: I think something like @JosefZ suggested is what you need.  CsvHelper does not have any capability to detect file encoding.

Comment: I solved it,  thanks to your suggestion @JosefZ